# Extract number groups from a string and separate them

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a VBA macro to extract number sequences from a string and separate them.
For example the cell A1 value is `Order No.2 123 Order No.3 234 Order No.4 345`
After the macro the cell B1 value should be `123, 234, 345`
Since the char number of `A & BBB` in `Order No.A BBB` is not fixed, e.g. `Order No.324 1814406`, I cannot use a left function to clear a specific number of char to solve the problem. Could someone can give me some suggestion?

Please let me know if I can clarify anything for you.
Below is the macro I have now, this can clear the non number char and return `2, 123, 3, 234, 4, 345`

```
Sub Testing()
str = Range("A1")
For x = 1 To Len(Range("A1"))
    If Not IsNumeric(Mid(str, x, 1)) Then 
        Mid(str, x) = " "
    End If
Next x
    Range("B1") = Replace(Application.Trim(str), " ", ", ")
End Sub
```

Comment: My suggestion: You could do this with a Regular Expression like https://regex101.com/r/E1Q6FL/1/ There are several tutorials how to use Regular Expressions in VBA (here on Stack Overflow as well as on Google).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Split function could be useful like that

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()
    Dim inp As String
    inp = "Order No.221 123 Order No.13 234 Order No.4 345"
    Dim v As Variant
    v = Split(inp, " ")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(v) + 2 To UBound(v) Step 3
        Debug.Print v(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```